How to get an daily average across many years of data
I have a large amount of data and I am trying to calculate median values for each day of the year across 25 years of data.
The median values will be useful so that we can compare current figures to the long-term median on each date.
This is an example of the data I'm using. The values I'm concerned about analyzing are in columns B and C. The data goes back to mid 1999 and for the most part is continuous data, except for labels for the columns which are interspersed every 52 rows:


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I don't know if I understood correctly. Is the median to be calculated from the same days and months in individual years?
If so, assuming addresses as in the screenshot below, the following formula can be used (in E2 and copy down):
=MEDIAN(FILTER($B$1:$B$60, IFERROR((DAY($A$1:$A$60)=DAY(D2))*(MONTH($A$1:$A$60)=MONTH(D2)),0)))



If you have M365 you can use GROUPBY. There are a few ways to do it based on your output preference. Here are two.

Use TEXT to format the date in your preferred way of displaying Month and Day:
=LET(
data,$B$3:$D$1098,
GROUPBY(TEXT(TAKE(data,,1),"xxxx-mm-dd"),TAKE(data,,-2),MEDIAN,3,0)
)


You could also use day then month with "dd-mm" or month then day with "mm-dd", or something else.

Return different columns for month and day:
=LET(
data,$B$3:$D$1098,
dates,TAKE(data,,1),
grp,GROUPBY(HSTACK(MONTH(dates),DAY(dates)),TAKE(data,,-2),MEDIAN,1,0),
VSTACK({"Month","Day","Sales","Volume"},grp)
)


Change the column headers to whatever you prefer.
This is what both look like:


If GROUPBY is available:
enter in E2:
=LET(
    data_with_labels, A2:C100,
    data, FILTER(
        data_with_labels,
        BYROW(data_with_labels, LAMBDA(r, SUM(--ISNUMBER(r)) = 3))
    ),
    date_, CHOOSECOLS(data, 1),
    year_day, DAYS(date_, DATE(YEAR(date_), 1, 1)) + 1,
    GROUPBY(year_day, CHOOSECOLS(data, 2, 3), MEDIAN, 0, 0)
)


